# Can someone help me to prove this identity?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \binom{4n}{4i+1}=2^{4n-2}$$

Comment: Hint: compute $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{4n}{k}i^{\tau k}=(1+i^\tau)^{4n}$$ for $\tau\in\{0,1,2,3\}$ and combine such results.

Comment: Have you tried induction? Base case is trivial. For the induction case use Pascal's rule and binomial theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$
\frac{1+(-1)^{k-1}+i^{k-1}+(-i)^{k-1}}4=\big[k\equiv1\pmod{4}\big]
$$
where $[\dots]$ are [Iverson brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket). Then
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\binom{4n}{4i+1}
&=\sum_{k=0}^{4n}\binom{4n}{k}\frac{1+(-1)^{k-1}+i^{k-1}+(-i)^{k-1}}4\\
&=\frac{2^{4n}-0^{4n}-i(1+i)^{4n}+i(1-i)^{4n}}4\\[6pt]
&=\frac{16^n}4
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thanks for helping me. Would this method give solution:  $$\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\binom{4n}{4i+1}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\binom{‌​4n}{4i+1}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\binom{4n}{4i+1}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}‌​\binom{4n}{4n-4i-1}$$ etc.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. The two sides are equal due to a basic binomial identity.